# ActionScript 3 popup

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I make a DisplayObject popup like Flex PopUpManager in AS3?

Comment: I don't think there is a built in mechanism for this.

Comment: You will have to create your own popupmanager and add its container in front of every other layers.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [PopUpManager of AS3Commons UI Layers](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-ui/layers/). A pure and slim AS3 implementation that I am developing - meant to be an alternative to the Flex thing.